# apply DayLightSavingTime to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimezone

I get a NSDate from a UIDatePicker (timePicker) which is converted to the users time zone but it is one hour off because I'm in Summer Time.

So I tried to check if the User is in Summer Time if yes it should add the time to the NSDate/dateInUserTimezone.

How can I achieve this?

```
func convertTimeZone() ->NSDate {
        var date = timePicker.date
        print(date)
        var formatter = NSDateFormatter()

        let timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: userTimeZone())
        formatter.timeZone = timeZone
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        var isDaylightSavingTime: Bool {
            return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().daylightSavingTime
        }
        print(isDaylightSavingTime)

        var daylightSavingTimeOffset: NSTimeInterval {
            return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().daylightSavingTimeOffset
        }

        let dateInUserTimezone = formatter.dateFromString(formatter.stringFromDate(date))

        return dateInUserTimezone!
    }

    func userTimeZone() -> String {
        return NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().abbreviation ?? ""
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSDate is inherently in UTC (it has no timezone). Best to save/transfer your dates in UTC. Then, you can convert this UTC time stamp to any time zone of your preference. Instead of detecting whether the user is DST or not, try converting to your preferred time zone. Here's an example of how you would convert any date to local time zone.

```
var date = ...
var myTimeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
var df = NSDateFormatter()
df.timeZone = myTimeZone
df.dateFormat = "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"
df.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: with my method it works the time zone is right. It is just one hour off because of the DayLightSavingTime. And I'm wondering how I can apply this.

Comment: What time zones are you converting between?

Comment: I get the NSDate from UIPicker in UTC and then it gets the time zone with abbreviation from the userTimeZone function. So that converts the timePicker.date to the time which is selected on the device. I just have to add this one hour from the dayLightSavingTimeOffset.

Comment: Your API to get user time zone is incorrect. Perhaps you should use `NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()`. What is userTimeZone()?

Comment: Apparently you are right. userTimeZoner() is the function at the bottom of my post

Comment: Glad to help. if this helped, can you accept the answer as correct.

Comment: sorry another Question. With code provided it gives back a String. But what do I have to do that I get a NSDate Object back?

Comment: You already have the NSDate from time picker. NSDate is always UTC/GMT. There is no time zone in it.